# How I can get object as parameter from Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I can't understand how I can use getParameter() with object, as I understand it's impossible. And what I should do?

Currency currency = req.getParameter("currencies");-it doesn't work.

My servlet:

```
public class AddPurseServlet extends HttpServlet {
private PurseDao purseDao;
private CurrencyDao currencyDao;

@Override
public void init() throws ServletException {
    purseDao = (PurseDao) getServletContext().getAttribute("purseDao");
    currencyDao = (CurrencyDao) getServletContext().getAttribute("currencyDao");
}

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    List<Currency> currencies = currencyDao.getAll();

    req.setAttribute("currencies", currencies);

    req.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/view/addPurse.jsp").forward(req, resp);
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpSession session = req.getSession();
    User user = (User) session.getAttribute("user");
    String amount = req.getParameter("amount");
    Currency currency = req.getParameter("currencies");

    Purse purse = new Purse(user, currency, new BigDecimal(amount), new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));

    purseDao.insert(purse);

    resp.sendRedirect("userPage");
}
}
```

And my jsp page where I require parameters of currency and amount:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello USER!</h1>
<div class="container">
<h1>Save User</h1>
<form method="post" action="addPurse">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Currency</label>
        <select>
            <c:forEach var="currency" items="${currencies}">
                <option value="${currency.id}">${currency.name}</option>
            </c:forEach>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Amount</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="amount" placeholder="Amount">
    </div>
    <input class="btn btn-default btn-xs" type="submit" value="Save">
    <a class="btn btn-default btn-xs" href="usersList" role="button">cancel</a>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *it doesn't work.* is not an error description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I understand from your code is that you are trying to populate a list of currencies and then try to set some amount for the currency object.

For this, you have your currencies identified by a unique ID. That's perfect.Now what you need to understand is that you don't really need the object from the JSP page. All you need is the ID of the currency.

So I would go around and modify your JSP with something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello USER!</h1>
<div class="container">
<h1>Save User</h1>
<form method="post" action="addPurse">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Currency</label>
        <select id="currency" name="currency">
            <c:forEach var="currency" items="${currencies}">
                <option value="${currency.id}">${currency.name}</option>
            </c:forEach>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Amount</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="amount" placeholder="Amount">
    </div>
    <input class="btn btn-default btn-xs" type="submit" value="Save">
    <a class="btn btn-default btn-xs" href="usersList" role="button">cancel</a>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, coming to your servlet. Seeing the keywords "DAO" and "CurrencyDAO", I assume that you are using JPA/Hibernate. So you need to modify the code with something like this:

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpSession session = req.getSession();
    User user = (User) session.getAttribute("user");
    String amount = req.getParameter("amount");
    String currencyid = req.getParameter("currency");
//Get your currency object from database
    Currency currencyToBeEdited = currencyDao.findById(Integer.parseInt(currencyid));

//Add the code to set the amount and save it back to the database

    Purse purse = new Purse(user, currency, new BigDecimal(amount), new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));

    purseDao.insert(purse);

    resp.sendRedirect("userPage");
}
```

Note: I am not 100% sure about your goal but I have provided the advice that would hopefully take you in the right direction

Comment: Thank you so much, your answer helped me.

Comment: glad to know that it helped

Answer (score 2):

Parameters are strings.

If your currency is an enum

```
final String currencyStr = request.getParameter("currency");
final Currency currency = Stream.of(Currency.values()).filter(currency -> currency.code.equals(currencyStr)).findFirst().orElse(null));
```

Comment: No, my currency isn't an enum.

Comment: You'll have to derive your currency object from the string somehow.